# events from from a pod and deployment redirected to a file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In Kubernetes how to get events from from a pod and deployment redirected to a file? is this can be done by jsonpath or will have to use linux/unix commands?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the events you can use `kubectl get events` and `grep` for the resource type.

```
kubectl get events |grep 'pod/<pod-name>'
```

Or (complex to me)

if you want to use `jsonpath`, I have just build the two columns, you can built as much you need.

```
 kubectl get events -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.firstTimestamp}{"\t"}{.reason}{"\n"}{end}'
<nil>   Scheduled
2021-06-16T21:47:44Z    Pulling
2021-06-16T21:47:45Z    Pulled
2021-06-16T21:47:45Z    Created
2021-06-16T21:47:46Z    Started
2021-06-16T21:47:44Z    MissingClusterDNS
2021-06-16T21:48:46Z    Killing
<nil>   Scheduled
2021-06-16T21:49:02Z    Pulling
2021-06-16T21:49:03Z    Pulled
2021-06-16T21:49:04Z    Created
2021-06-16T21:49:04Z    Started
2021-06-08T20:27:17Z    MissingClusterDNS
2021-06-08T20:27:22Z    MissingClusterDNS
2021-06-08T20:27:17Z    MissingClusterDNS
2021-06-16T21:49:02Z    MissingClusterDNS
2021-06-08T20:27:20Z    MissingClusterDNS
```

Example, I have added 3rd column `message` in below command:

```
kubectl get events -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.firstTimestamp}{"\t"}{.reason}{"\t"}{.message}{"\n"}{end}'
```

But if you are in `shell` environement, `grep`-ing is simpler.